# jQuery: IE returning empty for ID

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

I have a heartbeat interval which calls a function every few seconds. This function then in turn makes a JSON request to the server via jQuery, the server returns the JSON response and a success jQuery function like usual. Within the success function it does another jQuery function, a foreach for each id. From each id another function is called, function(this). That function then makes another JSON request via jQuery and gets the data.

e.g.:

```
function function() {
 jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
  $.ajax({
   success: function(data){
    jQuery.each(data.ids, function() {
     function2(this);
    }
   });
  });
 });
}

function function2(id) {

 //In IE id is empty here

 jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
  $.ajax({
   // In IE id has data here in it, WTF
   success: function(data){
    //In IE id is empty here
   }
  });
 });
}
```

Also, keep in mind these aren't the real function names, just here as an example for what the actual problem is.  The problem is that in IE 7 and IE 8, the id variable is EMPTY.  In every other browser the ID is never empty.  I don't understand why.  Can someone please help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how IE handles your syntax, the multiple `jQuery.noConlict()` calls aren't needed, instead your call (if you need `$` inside) should look like this:

```
function function2(id) {
 (function($){
  $.ajax({
   success: function(data){
   }
  });
 })(jQuery);
}
```

Or instead, wrap all your functions inside one `(function($) { /* code */ })(jQuery);`, calling `.noConflict()` as well if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yeesh, it looks like you found a hiccup in jQuery's cross-compatibility. I'd try binding the `.each()` to `this`, and using `console.log()` liberally until you find where the script stops working. Using IE's developer tools (hit f12), you should be able to at least track down the issue.

Comment: even i faced the same problem , as your doing it in ajax complete sometimes IE has no idea about that DOM